# cfn-signal no working in ubuntu stack timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
TestInstance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  CreationPolicy:
    ResourceSignal:
      Timeout: PT5M
  Properties:                
    ImageId: ami-02a599eb01e3b3c5b      
    InstanceType: t2.micro
    KeyName: TestKey   
    SecurityGroupIds: !Ref sg
    UserData: 
      Fn::Base64: |
          #!/bin/bash -x               
          apt install -y python-pip
          pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz                                              
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack teststack --resource TestInstance --region ap-southeast-2
```

Comment: Can you provide exact error message?

Comment: Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) within the specified duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `cfn-signal` is  incorrect. This is because it has **different location** on `Ubuntu` than on `Amazon Linux`.

- Amazon Linux: `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal`
- Ubuntu: `/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal`

Therefore, instead of

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack teststack --resource TestInstance --region ap-southeast-2
```

you should have :

```
/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack teststack --resource TestInstance --region ap-southeast-2
```

If this won't help, please double check that `teststack` and `ap-southeast-2` are correct. Also make sure the instance has **internet access**.